# NoClassDefFoundError error when migrating from Keycloak 18 to Keycloak 19 using legacy images

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am facing an error when migrating from Keycloak 18 to Keycloak 19 using the docker image:  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1-legacy.

I am getting this error:
FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Error during startup: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link /keycloak/legacy/spi/LegacyUserStorageProviderFactory (Module "deployment.keycloak.jar" from Service Module Loader): org/keycloak/storage/UserStorageProviderFactory

The issue is solved here
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/13954

But this is for standalone server not keycloak deployed using docker containers.
Can anyone modify this solution to docker containers?